# Visual Studio/Resharper How to see summury of the methods with return types

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

In class explorer it is easy to see brief list of methods with their parameters,
Is there somewhere to see list of methods with their returned types? 
Is there a way to do a search for methods/properties by a filter on their returned result type or type of their arguments? Either in VS or using Resharper or some other extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper's [File Structure window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.2/Reference__Windows__File_Structure_Window.html) includes return values, as does the drop down list shown when you invoke the [Go to Member](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.2/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_File_Member.html) search.